# Install Centos7 with kickstart file fails with "entering emergency mode"

Tags: centos, kickstart

I've created and tested a kickstart file using virtualbox. However, when I try to use the same kickstart file on a different computer, I get "Warning: Could not boot", "Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"" and "Entering emergency mode", after about 3 minutes. It doesn't seem to even try to download the kickstart file.

Here is what I tried:

- looking at the rdsosreport file. It doesn't seem to have any usefull information, just shows "loop: module loaded" at 12 seconds, and then "warning: could not boot" at 199.
- the same image (iso) on the virtualbox virtual machine, and it just installed without problems.
- both booting from CD and USB pen drive (created with dd). Same result.
- referencing the kickstart file both by host name and by IP address, with the same result. The file is on a server in the same network.
- from the dracut command prompt, to ping the server where the kickstart file is, by name, gives me "Unknown host", and by IP address I get "Network is unreachable". I'm not sure if this is relevant because I'm don't know if the network is suppose to be available at this point.

Where else can I look at to try to find what's wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I installed the system without the kickstart file, and it turns out I don't have internet connection. This is an old laptop, so [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=47382) may have something to do with it.

Comment: How are you downloading the kickstart file? Cobbler/PXE or iPXE?

Comment: i just created a python http server on a different machine (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`) with the kickstart file, and then point to it using `linux ks=http://IP-OR-NAME:8000/ks.txt`. I do not get any request on the server